# How can I convert JSON to listed array?

Tags: php, json

I need to convert this JSON into a specfic type of array. JSON array structure is on Pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/Ffs83yMz

I need the array like:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (    
        [title] => 'Meleigh&#8217;s 7th Birthday'
        [event_url] => 'http://www.paintpartyplace.com/party/meleighs-7th-birthday/'
        [event_image] => 'http://www.paintpartyplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/partythumb.png'

    )
[2] => Array
    (
        title] => 'Meleigh&#8217;s 7th Birthday'
        [event_url] => 'http://www.paintpartyplace.com/party/meleighs-7th-birthday/'
        [event_image] => 'http://www.paintpartyplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/partythumb.png'
    )
)
```

Comment: `json_decode` not enough? http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: Be sure to add a tag for the relevant language when you ask code questions

Comment: the code under "I need the array like" is probably PHP

Comment: The "JSON" you showed is not valid JSON. You are missing `[ ... ]` around the list of objects, keys must be strings, and strings must be in double quotes, not single quotes. I'm afraid there is no straightforward way to convert the data you have.

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling, there was actually more wrong with the JSON. I changed my answer accordingly. Tim, did you generate this file yourself (aka can you generate it as valid JSON) or did you get it from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHP (your result is in PHP code)

Edit: I just noticed that your JSON is not valid (thanks, Felix Kling, I missed that). Key names and value names MUST be in double quotes `"`. Right now you have no quotes around your keys and you have single quotes `'` around the values. Also, your file, as it is a set, must begin with `[` and end with `]`. PHP will refuse to parse invalid JSON.

If you use valid JSON, you can use `json_decode`. I made a [new paste](http://pastebin.com/30KkPg9z%20%27%27proper%20JSON%27%27) for you with valid data.

```
<?php
print_r(json_decode(
    file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=30KkPg9z'),
    true
));
```